# I'm trying to describe a sound i.e. a popping sound which is metallic. How do I phrase such a sound?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests, adjectives

The best I could come up with is ***Metallic Pop*** which doesn't suit the rest of the writing style at all, which has a bit more imaginative use of adjectives. 
What other phrase could I use to describe such a sound? The sound I was thinking of was somewhat similar to the **Hangouts Pop** notification sound.
A word that sounds serious, brooding even. If possible.

If I had to describe it, it would be the Hangouts Pop sound, but more metallic nature.

And ***ping*** IS a good word for it, yes. But it feels too...short? I would really like to know if there was a *phrase* to describe it? Something ominous yet sounding high-tech.

If it helps in anyway, the object making the sound is what I call a **compressible bag**, which takes in a special kind of radiation and compresses its contents into a miniscule dimension. To make it easier to carry. Once the compression is done, it makes the sound. To say that the process is over.

Comment: "ping" may work.

Comment: Is there any way you could attach a wav or mp3 of the sound in question?

Comment: What is responsible for making this noise? If it's an everyday object,  you might get some quick answers.

Comment: I tried searching for the sound effect online. All I could find was "metallic twang" sounds @MaxWilliams.

Comment: Uhhhh...Its not really an everyday object @Mari-LouA.

Comment: What is the object?

Comment: On the google hangouts page, the page source might have it as an audio tag or something.

Comment: Some possible words for mechanical impact sounds include ping, clank, clang, clunk, thunk, twang, crunch. Without hearing the sound it is difficult to make a guess as to how to describe it. Words for sounds tend to be onomatopoeic.

Comment: Thanks @SpehroPefhany!! I'm pretty sure one of the words you used would be perfect

Comment: Another possibility might be "chime" (typically deeper pitched than ping, more melodic than many of the other suggestions) - as Spehro Pefhany says, it's difficult to know which option would be most accurate without hearing the sound in question.

Answer (score 1):

You can try "plinked" defined in dictionary as:
verb
past tense: plinked; past participle: plinked
emit a short, sharp, **metallic** or ringing sound.
"the sounds echoed and plinked like bells"
play a musical instrument in such a way as to produce short, sharp, ringing sounds.
"a daughter dutifully plinks through her piano lesson"